# Function output of JavaScript function not showing in html

Tags: javascript, html

The Javascript code is working but I don't know how I can make it work in HTML. I want to link it to an external Javascript file.

```
 function find_longest_string(input_array) {

  var large = input_array[0].length;     //storing the length of each word in the variable large
  input_array.map(var_new => large = Math.max(large, var_new.length)); //used map to check the largest word
  answer = input_array.filter(var_new => var_new.length == large);    //storing the words which are larger

  return answer[0]; //displaying the first largest word
}

console.log(find_longest_string(['mystery', 'brother', 'aviator','crocodile','pearl','orchard','crackpott']))
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script src="findLongestWord.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only issue you're having I suspect: you didn't check the browser's console. Press F12 to open the dev tools, then click the Console tab. You will see the output in there. Your HTML is fine, provided the script is in the same folder as the html file.

Comment: Please clarify the actual problem. Where in the "HTML" do you expect the output? As visible text in the `<body>`?

Comment: @13ezoo Can you be more specific about the problem? Do you want to get the output of that function get printed somewhere or displayed on your HTML page? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes @Dinindu Gunathilaka

Comment: The fastest way: `document.body.innerHTML += find_longest_string(...);` In the long run you'll want to create an element for output and use that.

Comment: @13ezoo _"Yes"_ doesn't really work as an answer for two different questions that ask for further details/clarification ;)

Comment: @13ezoo Hey okay I got you. I have put an answer. You may refer and let me know whether you overcome the problem. And always open to any clarifications :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to print or display the output of that function on the web page.

If that's the case. There are various ways to accomplish this.

Before I go any further, I'd want to point out that you are, in fact, printing something, which is what you intended for your function.
But you can't see it since it's printed in the console.
You may view this by using the `F12` key after loading your website.
The console will then appear, and the needed output will be printed.

And here's one method for displaying your output in an HTML page.

You just have to replace your `console.log()`  with the `document.write()`.

```js
 function find_longest_string(input_array) {

  var large = input_array[0].length;     //storing the length of each word in the variable large
  input_array.map(var_new => large = Math.max(large, var_new.length)); //used map to check the largest word
  answer = input_array.filter(var_new => var_new.length == large);    //storing the words which are larger

  return answer[0]; //displaying the first largest word
}

document.write(find_longest_string(['mystery', 'brother', 'aviator','crocodile','pearl','orchard','crackpott']))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script src="findLongestWord.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is another method to achieve this.
You can add an html element and change the content of that particular element by using `document.getElementById("id name of the element").innerHTML`.

Here is the code snippet.

```js
function find_longest_string(input_array) {

  var large = input_array[0].length;     //storing the length of each word in the variable large
  input_array.map(var_new => large = Math.max(large, var_new.length)); //used map to check the largest word
  answer = input_array.filter(var_new => var_new.length == large);    //storing the words which are larger

  return answer[0]; //displaying the first largest word
}
const largest_word = find_longest_string(['mystery', 'brother', 'aviator','crocodile','pearl','orchard','crackpott']);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =largest_word
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script src="findLongestWord.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```